# Can not access function inside a class

Tags: python

see my comments and please help me

```
class cercle:

    Pi = 3,14159

    def __init__(self):

        self._rayon = 1
        self._abcisse = 1
        self._ordonnee = 1

        if self._rayon < 0:
            return -self._rayon #i want to take the opposite value if it is negative

    def aire(self):
        self.Pi * self._rayon ** 2 #How to do the power 2 ?

    def permietre(self):
        cercle.Pi * self._rayon * 2

    aire(self) #How to call the aire method to go inside ?
```

i want to call the aire method but i can't because there is the problem with argument self

but i have
File "labspoo.py", line 26, in cercle
    print(self.aire())
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
Mac:~ MatR$

Answer (score 0):

```
class cercle:
    Pi = 3.14159 # Changed from , to a . which is the decimal separator in Python.

    def __init__(self):
        self._rayon = 1
        self._abcisse = 1
        self._ordonnee = 1

        if self._rayon < 0:
            return -self._rayon #i want to take the opposite value if it is negative

    def aire(self):
        self.Pi * self._rayon ** 2 #How to do the power 2 ?

    def permietre(self):
        cercle.Pi * self._rayon * 2

x = cercle()
x.aire()
```

`aire` is a function of the class `cercle`, there for you need to instanciate `cercle` first and put it in a variable.
You can then use that variable (`x` in my case) to call on your `aire` function.

`self` is a mandatory parameter on all class functions within a class that you use to grab variables inside the class, for instance `self._rayon`.

Comment: I believe using this syntax makes `Pi` a `tuple`. I think comma (`,`) should be replaced with period (`.`) to make `Pi` a `float`

Comment: @Nhor You're very much correct. I looked past this for some reason.